# run time error running the stack which could be due to array size

Tags: java

I created a class that runs a stack. However when I run the main class it gives a runtime error. The class runs like a stack but when the numbers entered go over the stack size its supposed to call a method that copies the array  add more size to the stack.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
at IntegerStack.push(IntegerStack.java:26)
at Lab15.main(Lab15.java:18)

I think the problem lies within this class I dont know exactly where my problem lies. I could be wrong but it could be with my copy of the array.

```
            import java.util.Arrays;


         public class IntegerStack 

{

private int stack [];
private int top; 


public IntegerStack(int SIZE) 
{
    stack = new int [SIZE];
    top = -1;
}

public void push(int i) 
{
    if (top == stack.length)

        extendStack();

    else

       stack[++top]= i;

}

public int pop() 
{

    return stack[top--];
}

public int peek()
{

    return stack[top];  

}


public boolean isEmpty() 
{
    if ( top == -1)

        return true;
    else    
        return false;

}

private void extendStack()
{

    stack = Arrays.copyOf(stack, 2 * stack.length);
}

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void push(int i) 
{
    if (top == stack.length-1)

        extendStack();

    else

       stack[++top]= i;

}
```

Comment: This has no explanation at all, evidently this is a homework task.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
    public void push(int i) 

{
    if (top == stack.length)

        extendStack();

    else

       stack[++top]= i;

    }
```

The reason is that if top is equal to the size of the stack, then you are incrementing your counter by 1 and then trying to insert into the stack array at that position:
stack[++top]= i;
This isn't correct because it will be one place higher than the maximum, as the increment is before adding. Try:
stack[top++] = i;

You will also need to change your constructor to start the variable top at 0 instead of -1.

That way is increments after using the variable top.

Alternatively you can put a minus 1 in the if statement to make it like this:
if (top == stack.length -1). This is because your array starts at 0.

An array of size 5 will have spaces 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 but not a space for 5.

Comment: If top is set up to start at 0 (as it should) rather than -1 then it will work fine.

Comment: Thank you this helped. I think there are other issues with my code that I must fix before this works correctly